# Преобразование python-проекта в .exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe

Перерыл весь Гугл, но не смог найти что-нибудь дельное.
Суть проблемы: у меня есть python проект, который из себя представляет набор файлов для того чтобы работало приложение на PyQt5. Пытаюсь его скомпилировать в .exe файл. После компиляции и запуска выдает ошибку что либо вообще не видит модуль PyQt5, либо потом не видит .ui-файлы.
Подскажите пожалуйста:)

Comment: Вы что используете для преобразования?

Comment: Пробовал и auto-py-to-exe и pyInstaller

Comment: Python какой используется? В Pyinstaller можно принудительно добавить либу.

Comment: Не могу сейчас точно ответить, но скорее всего последняя версия (PyCharm использую, в нем вроде обновляется самостоятельно)

Comment: pon4ik попробуйте подготовить  [mcve], преобразовав который можно будет получить проблему, о которой вы пишите.